# Search for hotels with saunas

Tags: health, hotels, spa

Can you recommend a website for searching hotels with saunas or steam rooms worldwide? I often travel on business to different countries and for relaxation I like to regularly visit a sauna. However, searching for a suitable sauna nearby takes up a certain amount of time.

TripAdvisor can be used, but there is no filter for saunas.

Comment: booking.com has a search filter for 'spa and wellness centre' if that would suffice, although I assume that at least in the North European countries, some hotels will have a simple sauna without necessarily labelling it as a 'spa and wellness centre'.

Answer (score 6):

When you use a search website for hotels, there is usually many filters for the search criteria. One of them will be "Amenities" or "Property Facilities" or "Fun Things To Do".

For instance, on Agoda.com you can search for hotels and filter "Property Facitilies" by "Spa/Sauna".

[image: Agoda.com]

For instance, on Booking.com you can search for hotels and filter by "Fun Things To Do" and sauna is one of them.

[image: Booking.com]

On Kayak.com, they use "Amenities" to filter on "spa".

[image: Kayak.com]

Keep in mind, saunas are not easy to find in warmer climates. Most places use the term "spa" and will have sauna features in their hotel spa. I hope that helps.